# angular 8 accept number only custom directive working in desktop browsers.but not working in mobile chrome browser

Tags: regex, angular8, angular2-directives, mobile-chrome

i created a custom directive to accept only numbers. it is working fine in desktop browser and safari mobile version.but not working in mobile chrome version.

Anyone can help me on this issue.thanks in advance

this is my HTML and directive

```
  <input NumbersOnly  placeholder="{{ 'PlaceHolder.MobileNo' | translate }}" formControlName="mobileNo"  maxlength="7" >
```

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from "@angular/core";
@Directive({
  selector: "[NumbersOnly]",
})
export class NumbersDirective {
  // Allow decimal numbers and negative values
  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^-?[0-9]+(\[0-9]*){0,1}$/g);
  // Allow key codes for special events. Reflect :
  // Backspace, tab, end, home
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ["Backspace", "Tab", "End", "Home", "-"];
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
  @HostListener("keydown", ["$event"])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    if (event.key.match(this.regex) == null) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working means ? It is accepting characters also ?

Comment: Yes in mobile chrome browser it accept characters to.but in desktop this directive is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I see you missed a dot in the regex. You don't need `g` modifier as the entire string must match.

Use

```
private regex: RegExp = /^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?$/;
```

Comment: regex is fine.but what happens is event.preventdefault() not working in mobile chrome browser

Comment: @streeker Ok, but that is not regex related.